# usage of $past macro in system verilog for a signal to high

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am a starter in system verilog.

I want to check on a falling edge of the signal whether it is high for the past 'n' number of cycles. Usage of ##n cycles doesn't work for me.

logic x,y;

x & y -> ##2 $past(y) -> $fell(y); this doesn't seem like working

with the condition of x & y, what I am checking is at the falling edge of 'y' the signal 'y' is high for past 2 cycles after the condition x& y is met

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to SVA.

In my answer i shall assume that you have defined a clock and are using this in your definition of "falling edge"

There are a few issues with your code and problem description. I only enumerate these to help with issues in the future:
- $past is not a macro but a system function
- You are not using the correct SVA implication operator. "->" is a blocking event trigger. The overlapping implication operator I guess you are after is |->
- ##2 $past(y) will actually insert a delay of 2 cycles, and then check that the past value of y was high. Really, you are checking that y is high one cycle after your initial trigger.

I am also not quite sure what your trigger condition is meant to be - x && y will spawn a property thread if both x and y are high. In fact, it won't trigger on a negedge of y.

In the following code I attempt to code up the SVA to your spec as I understood it. You can use a simple function to ensure that preceding n cycle, y was high. Feel free to replace $fell(y) with any trigger as required.

```
function bit y_high_preceding_n_cycles(int n)
 for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) begin
  // check if y wasnt high i cycles ago, just return 0
  if (!$past(y, i, , @(posedge clk))) return 0;
 end
 return 1;
endfunction

prop_label: assert property($fell(y) |-> y_high_preceding_n_cycles(n));
```

This will check that on detection of $fell(y), y was high the preceding n cycles. Note that the iteration of the for loop i==1 will by definition be redundant (as trigger on $fell(y) i.e. definitely $past(y) == 1 holds assuming no Xs).

Hope this helps.